# Recyclerview Multiple row layout

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I'm facing a problem dealing with multiple row layout in recycler view. I want to have 4 rows with different layout, this adapter only shows 2 layouts and doesnt show the next 2. please help me getting this issue fixed. I'm adding the adapter code below:

```
> package com.example.sikandar.recycler;


import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Sikandar on 10/1/2015.
 */
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Datalist> dataList;
    private static final int TYPE_holder1 = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_OPTION_holder2 = 2;
    private static final int TYPE_OPTION_holder3 = 3;
    private static final int TYPE_OPTION_holder4 = 4;


    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public View view;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            view = v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Datalist> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return TYPE_holder1;

            case 1:
                return TYPE_OPTION_holder2;

            case 2:
                return TYPE_OPTION_holder3;

            case 3:
                return TYPE_OPTION_holder4;

            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }


    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        switch (viewType) {
            case TYPE_holder1:
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder1, parent, false);
            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
            case TYPE_OPTION_holder2:
                View v1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder2, parent, false);
                // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
                ViewHolder vh1 = new ViewHolder(v1);
                return vh1;
            case TYPE_OPTION_holder3:
                View v2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder3, parent, false);
                // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
                ViewHolder vh2 = new ViewHolder(v2);
                return vh2;
            case TYPE_OPTION_holder4:
                View v3 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder4, parent, false);
                // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
                ViewHolder vh3 = new ViewHolder(v3);
                return vh3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }


    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element

        if(holder.getItemViewType()==TYPE_holder1) {
            TextView Email = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.emailbox);
            TextView phone = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.phonebox);
            TextView mobile = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.mobilebox);
            TextView buemail = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.buemailbox);
            TextView Padress = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.Paddress);
            TextView Caddress = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.Caddress);

            Email.setText(dataList.get(position).getEmail());
            phone.setText(dataList.get(position).getPhone());
           mobile.setText(dataList.get(position).getMobile());
            buemail.setText(dataList.get(position).getBuemail());
            Padress.setText(dataList.get(position).getPadress());
            Caddress.setText(dataList.get(position).getCadress());
        }
        else if (holder.getItemViewType()==TYPE_OPTION_holder2){
            TextView enrollment = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.enrollbox);
            TextView classs = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.classbox);
            TextView reg = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.regbox);
            TextView intake = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.intakebox);
            TextView degdur = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.degreebox);


            enrollment.setText(dataList.get(position).getEnrollment());
            classs.setText(dataList.get(position).getClasss());
            reg.setText(dataList.get(position).getReg());
            intake.setText(dataList.get(position).getIntake());
            degdur.setText(dataList.get(position).getDegDur());

        }
        else if (holder.getItemViewType()==TYPE_OPTION_holder3){
            TextView father = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.fatherbox);



            father.setText(dataList.get(position).getFatherName());
        }
        else if (holder.getItemViewType()==TYPE_OPTION_holder4){
            TextView comwork = (TextView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.combox);



            comwork.setText(dataList.get(position).getComWork());
        }


    }

    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 4;
    }
    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }
}
```

This is the datalist

```
package com.example.sikandar.recycler;

/**
 * Created by Sikandar on 10/1/2015.
 */
class Datalist {
    String email;
    String Mobile;
    String Phone;
    String DegDur;
    String Intake;
    String enrollment;
    String reg;
    String classs;
    String buemail;
    String Padress;
    String Cadress;
    String FatherName;
    String ComWork;




    public Datalist(String DegDur,String Cadress,String Paddress,String enroll,String FatherName,String clas,String mobile,String email,String reg,String intake,String Comwork,String buemail){
        this.DegDur=DegDur;
        this.Intake=intake;
        this.ComWork=Comwork;
        this.buemail=buemail;
        this.FatherName=FatherName;
        this.enrollment=enroll;
        this.Padress=Paddress;
        this.Cadress=Cadress;
        this.classs=clas;
        this.Mobile=mobile;
        this.email=email;
        this.reg=reg;
    }


    public String getDegDur(){
        return DegDur;
    }
    public String getIntake(){
        return Intake;
    }
    public String getComWork(){
        return ComWork;
    }
    public String getBuemail(){
        return buemail;
    }
    public String getFatherName(){
        return FatherName;

    }
    public String getEnrollment(){
        return enrollment;
    }
    public String getPadress(){
        return Padress;
    }
    public String getCadress(){
        return Cadress;

    }
    public String getClasss(){
        return classs;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }
    public String getMobile(){
        return Mobile;
    }
    public String getPhone(){
        return Phone;
    }
    public String getReg(){
        return reg;
    }
}
```

this is where adding items in datalist

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.scrollableview);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


        email="Sikandar44iqbal@yahoo.com";
        Mobile="+923115117085";
        Phone="05178601";
        DegDur="4 Years";
        Intake="2013 Fall";
        enrollment="01-134132-180";
        reg="3375";
        classs="BSCS 5B";
        buemail="1234466465@bui.com";
        Padress="Houe 03, main college road, F-7/3 Islamabad.";
        Cadress="Houe 03, main college road, F-7/3 Islamabad.";
        FatherName="Zafar Iqbal";
        ComWork="Not Completed!";

        ArrayList<Datalist> dataList = new ArrayList<Datalist>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++ ) {

            dataList.add(new Datalist(DegDur,Cadress,Padress,enrollment,FatherName,classs,Mobile,email,reg,Intake,ComWork,buemail));
        }

        if (simpleRecyclerAdapter == null) {
            simpleRecyclerAdapter = new MyAdapter(dataList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(simpleRecyclerAdapter);
        }
```

Comment: How many items are in the dataList.size();  It look like there are only two items being returned.

Comment: i have added the datalist please have a look and see if u can help.

Comment: I can help but I would need to know how many items are in your data set. It is only showing two items because there are only two items in your data set.

Comment: I have added the part where data is being added in the list.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++ )  You are only adding two items to the adapter

Comment: so i have to add 4 items as i have 4 rows?

Comment: it worked thanks bruh. cheers

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: AnyBody landed here while looking multiple row demo http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/10/android-multiple-row-layout-using.html can simply refer this.